# How to animate changing order in UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8

I have a table view with 10 items. I can click a button and their order changes.
Then I reload this with the following code (I have and will ever have only one section):

```
[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic]
```

I tried different animations, but nothing works as I want.
I want the rows to slide into their new positions. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can animate the transitions with `UITableView` methods [beginUpdates and endUpdates](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW53), in conjunction with [moveRowAtIndexPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:).

Answer (score 2):

What I did:

1. `[tableView beginUpdates]`
2. Save all current cells to NSMutableArray. The model object is also stored in custom cell property.
3. Change data source.
4. Iterate over cells in array (index i), for each cell iterate over data source array (index j). If object in cell and in data source is the same, move cell from position i to position of object in data source array (j).
5. `[tableView endUpdates]`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample of sorting animation with asc/desc

```
 table.beginUpdates()
 for (index,_) in tableviewItems.enumerated(){
     let newRow = tableviewItems.count - index - 1
     table.moveRow(at: IndexPath(row: index, section: 0), to: IndexPath(row: newRow, section: 0))
 }
 tableviewItems.reverse()
 table.endUpdates()
```